# How can I split the screen when the screen splitting widget is not visible?

Tags: interface

I know the basics of splitting the screen/creating more of them.
While I can split the windows at the right I can't do that on the left, because those typical lines on the left lower corner are missing. Can I make them appear somehow?

[image: 3 screens]

Comment: Can you share the .blend file to be able to help you?

Comment: Why do you need to split the windows on the left? Unless I am misunderstanding your question, can't you just split it on the right and modify the left panel?

Comment: i can avoid spliting the left panel and use the ones on the right. I am just curious why the split lines are gone on the left panel.

Comment: i will share the file when i found out how to share files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the dividing line between two windows where your cursor changes into a double arrow (horizontal or vertical).  Right-click to activate the Area options menu which has two options: Split Area, and Join Area.  You want Split Area.  Then move your cursor into the window you would like to split.

In your case, there is no divider on the bottom or left, so you'll have to use the boundary on the top (between the 3D view and the info bar) or the right.

Comment: ... but now i want to close the single panel on the right; how?

Comment: Closing a single panel that borders a split set of panels is not possible in the blender UI as of 2.78.  It might be possible to frob the various panel fields in python to arrange things how you want, but I never worked up enough ambition to figure out the details.  For now, just drag the divider so far to the right that your properties panel is only 10 pixels wide.  You'll thank yourself when you want to access it later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Open new window by pulling the right top corner
- Once you do that you should find the bottom left one in the new window
- Pull the left bottom corner to close the old one which didn't have the bottom left pull option

[image]